# Custom __eq__() function for Django field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-model-field

I need to have a `CharField` with custom `__eq__` function so that when I run `model_class.objects.filter(id=something)` instead of just checking equality of both strings, my custom `__eq__` function should be run. Or is there any other way to implement the same equality check other than creating a custom `__eq__` function.

[Edit]
My custom `__eq__` function involves cutting the string into various sections and evaluating each section differently. My point is, it does not have an equivalent SQL statement.

Comment: You are overriding `==`, not `=`. Nitpicking aside, the equality there is converted to an SQL statement, so no, it won't run your custom Python code. If you elaborate what your custom `__eq__` function actually does maybe someone can help.

Comment: The problem is that my custom equality function does not have an equivalent SQL statement. If it had one I could've used custom field lookup functions.

Comment: If there's no equivalent SQL, what are you expecting any custom code to do? `filter` runs a query in the database by definition.